# GMail api users().history().list returns 'nextPageToken', but no 'history' field?

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api

I use the GMail API's [`history.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list) to retrieve a list of changed messages, this works fine with several pages of history - but sometimes when a `nextPageToken` is returned, it is used to retrieve the next page, which is returned **without** a `history` field. No `HttpError` is raised.

```
results = self.service.users ().history ().list (userId = self.account, startHistoryId = start).execute ()
if 'history' in results:
  yield results['history']

while 'nextPageToken' in results:
  pt = results['nextPageToken']
  results = self.service.users ().history ().list (userId = self.account, startHistoryId = start, pageToken = pt).execute ()
  yield results['history'] # this fails with missing 'history' member.
```

Comment: are you expecting a certain result but not there? What if there's really nothing to display?

Comment: If there is nothing more to display, then there should not be a `nextPageToken`. This is how I know that I have reached the end of the list. If I get a `nextPageToken`, but no more results, without any error, I do not feel confident that something hasn't been left out because of some error somewhere - since this is incremental updates I might skip those missing updates when I do the next incremental update.

Comment: Possible to see a [mcve]?

Comment: @boardrider: this only happens very infrequently (once in thousands or millions of requests), full example is here (example at bottom): https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list

Answer (score 0):

You need to expect no results on history page if I understand the question right.

```
while 'nextPageToken' in response:
    page_token = response['nextPageToken']
    response = gcon.users().messages().list(userId='me', pageToken=page_token).execute()
    if response['resultSizeEstimate'] is 0:
        break
    email.extend(response['messages'])
return email
```

I think this will help.

```
if response['resultSizeEstimate'] is 0:
    break
```

Comment: I do not remember exactly, but I do not think there was a `resultSizeEstimate` field either. Anyway, that does not seem very relibale. Is it not for the entire query? And there are results returned, it is just that the `nextPageToken` indicates there are more results -- but there are not.